# Parse Xml using dom

Tags: android

**In this xml only image tag which is in user tag is parsed , rest are not working how to resolve this error.
     
        1
        Post found

```
    <url>http://industryvegas.com/pokerspyapp/central//f06d5d94b40d7af9dbba1bd601e5ae33</url>
    <title>test</title>
    <text>testimage</text>
    <image>http://industryvegas.com/pokerspyapp/uploads/posts/a5771bce93e200c36f7cd9dfd0e5deaa.jpg</image>
    <gcomments>
    <gcomment id="38" createdOn="1354269393" likes="1" user_like="false" comments="1">
    <user id="40" username="bhanusharma" user_level="2">
    <image>http://industryvegas.com/pokerspyapp/uploads/users/d645920e395fedad7bbbed0eca3fe2e0.jpg</image>
    </user>
    <text>test image</text>
    <image>http://industryvegas.com/pokerspyapp/uploads/comments/a5771bce93e200c36f7cd9dfd0e5deaa.jpg</image>
    <greplies></gcomment>
    <gcomment id="37" createdOn="1354268379" likes="1" user_like="false" comments="1">
    <user id="40" username="bhanusharma" user_level="2">
    <text>test image comment</text>
    <image>http://industryvegas.com/pokerspyapp/uploads/comments/a5bfc9e07964f8dddeb95fc584cd965d.jpg</image>
    <greplies></gcomment>
    </gcomments>
    </gpost>
    </response>**
```

Comment: <user/> does this tag got closed. What is the problem exactly can you explain in detail.

Comment: only image tag which is in first user tag is parsed and rest of image tag is not parsed....

Comment: If you are still getting the error pls put the error, and the code.